# How to loop through each node in a graph and check its degree - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to loop through all the nodes in undirected graph `G` then check if degree of node `i` is 1.

I tried the following:

```
s = ["s1" "s1" "s2" "n1" "n2" "n3" "n4" "n5"];
t = ["s2" "s3" "s3" "s1" "s2" "s1" "s2" "s3"];
G = graph(s,t);
p = plot(G,'LineWidth',2);

edges = G.Edges
vertices = G.Nodes

for i = vertices(:, 1)
    if degree(G, i) == 1
        fprintf('%s has degree of 1', i)
    end 
end
```

However, I got the following error:

> Node IDs must be numeric node indices or node names.

Why am I getting this error? are not the nodes already have names here?

Thanks

Comment: Run this code in the debugger (set a break point in Editor before running), then look at what `i` inside your loop is. If you don’t want to use the debugger, at least put a `disp(i)` inside the loop.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did that and what `disp(i)` shows is the list of node's names i.e., `
    {'s1'}
    {'s2'}
    {'s3'}
    {'n1'}
    {'n2'}
    {'n3'}
    {'n4'}
    {'n5'}
`

Comment: Is `i` one of those each loop iteration or all of them with only one loop iteration? `vertices(:, 1)` is a column, so it should iterate only once (`for` iterates over columns). I think you need to transpose that to iterate over the elements. Next, you need to do `i{1}` to extract the name from the cell to use for indexing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks a lot! Transposing helped in this, I had to convert `vertices` to array though as it was treated as a table.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @CrisLuengo I had to transpose `vertices`. I also had to convert it to array as it was showing as a table.

Here is the working version of the code.

```
s = ["s1" "s1" "s2" "n1" "n2" "n3" "n4" "n5"];
t = ["s2" "s3" "s3" "s1" "s2" "s1" "s2" "s3"];
 
G = graph(s,t);
p = plot(G,'LineWidth',2);
 
edges = G.Edges;
vertices = G.Nodes;
 
vertices_t =  transpose(table2array(vertices));
for i = vertices_t(:, :)
%     disp(degree(G, i))
    if degree(G, i) == 1
        fprintf('%s has degree of 1\n', i{1})
    end 
end
```